# Are there any security implications to changing the base of a hash?

Tags: hash

File this under "gosh, I'd hope not," but I've been surprised before.

I have a hash (HMAC SHA-1 specifically).  I need to store the full hash, but due to constraints outside my control, I can only use a limited number of characters to store it.  I chose to change to base-36 to make the hash a shorter length.

Changing to base-36 **makes the number of characters vary (between 27 and 31 instead of the original 40)**.  This made me wonder about possible security implications of changing the base.  Are there any?

Comment: Is there a reason why you went for Base36 instead of the normal Base64-to-ASCII?

Comment: @schroeder I could possibly use a URL-safe base-64 encoding, but base-36 was chosen because `toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`

Comment: That seems ... arbitrary ... why use that function?

Comment: You bolded the one part. Is that important? Why did you bold it?

Answer (score 4):

Changing the base does not change the underlying value in any way. The base itself is merely a form of mathematical representation.

#### Does changing the base make it shorter?

Yes and no, depending on how you look at it. A higher base will result in a shorter message, but with more symbols. In fact, the base number is exactly what describes the number of unique symbols in a given representation. You could, in theory, pick 2^160 different symbols, and then store your hash by just picking the one symbol that corresponds to it.

So the higher the base, the less characters you need to store the information, but the more complex your character set will become.

In the end, the amount of underlying information is and will always be 160 bits.

#### Is it a problem that the number of character vary?

No. As we saw before, changing the base does not give us any more information about the hash than we would already have.

Answer (score 3):

I want to store `seventeen thousand, eight hundred, ninety seven` but there's only space for 8 bytes. If I write `17897` does it reduces the security?

Of course not. The representation does not change anything... If you have space, you can fill an string with 17897 dots, and count the dots...

Comment: Ah, the base1 encoding :D

Comment: @MechMK1 would base0 encoding mean that you can encode an infinite amount of data in one character?  Oh wait no, that would be base infinity encoding... someone needs to work on that...

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1381/ :)

Answer (score -2):

No, since it's the same underlying number, it does not have any security implications.  Consider if there were: they would apply to every SHA-1 because an attacker could just change the base themselves.  (The answer would be different if the hash was truncated instead.)

Most libraries represent SHA-1 hashes as a base-16 number such as:

`bc74202f5aad8a824ebf6fb7e328f11dd09c2c6d`

However, it's just a big number.  Here it is in base-10:

`1075879955064864040725976314787412657512793255021`

And in base-36 via our modern lingua franca of JavaScript:

```
BigInt("0xbc74202f5aad8a824ebf6fb7e328f11dd09c2c6d").
  toString(36) // "m0hh4v3d74j4omuceropkdthqgkvka5"
```

It's certainly a shorter string.

Base-36 is a little "untidy" because 2<sup>160</sup> = 16<sup>40</sup>, but 2<sup>160</sup> = 36<sup>160 log<sub>36</sub>2</sup> = 36<sup>30.9482...</sup> (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704010/why-is-a-sha-1-hash-40-characters-long-if-it-is-only-160-bit)), so instead of nice neat 40 characters each time, the number of characters varies.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your own question (seemingly posted almost simultaneously)? Or is it supposed to have been a continuation of the question. It doesn't seem to be a very good answer since you are just saying you "would not expect any security implications" (which certainly is fine for you to expect, since it seems correct)... but this doesn't read as an answer.

Comment: This is not looking like a "security" question or answer at all. It's just explaining the basics of number systems.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I've reworded to address these comments.

Comment: "because an attacker could just change the base themselves" -- this logic doesn't follow and is odd. It's a strawman. The answer is: "Since SHA-1's output is a 160-bit number, normally represented in Base16, it can be represented in any base as long as it represents the same 160-bit value." And I'd focus on the more standard methods of representing that message digest instead of Base36.

Comment: And once you do that, your question becomes, "does changing the base change the message digest?" and the answer to that is simply "no". But the reasons are elementary math.